# proof to proposition involving dimension

Tags: linear-algebra

i came across the dimension theorem as a proposition in linear algebra.
dim(w1 + w2)=dim(w1)+dim(w2)+dim(w1 n w2).
w1 and w2 are subspaces of the vector space V.
I am trying to prove this using bases but i cant strike a formal proof.My reasoning is as follows:
basis of w1= U1,U2,...,Un
basis of w2= V1,V2,...,Vm.
suppose the basis of w1 and w2 are independent then dim(w1+w2)=dim(w1)+dim(w2).
suppose some elements of basis of W1 is linearly dependent on the basis of W2, then there exists some intersection of basis and the resulting basis of W1+W2= basis(w1)+basis(w2)-basis(w1 n w2).hence the dimension theorem.is it correct and how can it be turned into a more formal proof?

Answer (score 0):

The vector space $W_1 \cap W_2$ is a subspace of both $W_1$ and $W_2$, and so it has a basis $\mathcal B$ which is a linearly independent subset of both $W_1$ and $W_2$. We know that we can always take a linearly independent subset of a vector space and complete it to a basis of that space, and so do that with $\mathcal B$ for $W_1$ to obtain $\mathcal B \cup \mathcal S_1$, and also do that for $W_1$ to obtain $\mathcal B \cup \mathcal S_1$. What can be said about the sets $\mathcal B$, $\mathcal S_1$, and $\mathcal S_2$?

Hopefully this gives you some concrete objects with which to formalize your proof!